# Backup mac osx terminal commands history

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion

How can I backup the mac osx (lion) terminal commands history 
into a text file on desktop ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can do this by redirecting the output of history into a file.

`history > history.txt`

Comment: To create the file on desktop : $ history > /Users/username/Desktop/history.txt with username to be replace by yours

Comment: Can you import it back (say, to a different Mac) using `history < history.txt`?

Answer (score 15):

If you are using bash:

~/.bash_history

else if zsh:

~/.zsh_history

Comment: How would I import it on a new machine? @metakermit

Comment: @him229 just copy this file to your home folder (/Users/<username> or ~ for short) and open the terminal – you should see your old history.

Answer (score 7):

For all those who want to import the exported file @ncremins answer:

Export `history.txt` file using

```
history > history.txt
```

Get the `history.txt` to other system you want to import in
then run:

```
history -r history.txt
```

Comment: omz_history:fc:14: event not found: history.txt

Comment: @EdwinO. Is it when exporting or importing?

Comment: Importing in apple chip mac

Comment: I did from intel to apple it worked for me though

Answer (score 2):

As you are actually not talking about the shell or bash, you might want to simply use the "Export as text ..." menu point. This exports the whole line buffer into a text file.

Comment: That was so simple that I did not see it. Sorry to bother you guys!

Comment: I ll do it if I had enough reputation !! But I am a newbiehere :)

Comment: Short for: rolling on the floor, laughing

Answer (score 1):

#### My environment

- macos
- zsh
- oh-my-zsh

#### Backup and restore (to another machine)

Copy over your `~/.histfile` over to the new machine, and replace it. Then, restart your shell on the new machine and you should see the right output from `history`.

> I found the file from `echo $HISTFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

> history X > history.txt

Where X is the line you want the history file to start from..

For example, if you run history > history.txt it'll just give you the most recent 10 lines or something like that. But if you want to save all the commands for the current session (i.e. 1-965) you would need to run history 1 > history.txt...Same goes for if you only want the 100 most recent: history 866 > history.txt